# Initialize all variables to a common value except one TBD variable

Tags: python

How would a Pythonic function look that initializes 5+ variables to a value of False and then uses the function argument to know which one should be True?

Update:
Here is more detail...

```
def func(var_to_be_True):
    foo, bar, baz, ... = False, False, False, ...
    # more code based on which ones are False and which one is True...

func('bar')
```

Two questions:

1. I'd like to tell func which variable is True.  I'm showing it as a string, but it needs to be a variable name.
2. What if I have 20 variables.  Can I set up a loop to set everything to False?  Again, I'm stuck with this string confusion.

Seems basic.  I'm a noob and probably missing something fundamental.

Comment: Please be more __clear__

Comment: In Python "initialization of variables" is an anti-pattern, because variables in Python are not like variables in other languages. Variables in python are just names pointing to something in the object space; they are not "boxes" (or memory locations) that need to be initialized. I suspect if you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve, there might be a different more _pythonic_ way of solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you want, but this is one way:

```
def func(var1=False, var2=False, var3=False, var4=False, var5=False):
    pass
```

All the variables are `False` by default. You can invoke the function by setting the variable to `True`

```
func(var3=True)
```

By doing this, all others are `False` except `var3`

Comment: This does the trick.  Thanks so much.  If I have 20 variables, is there a way to do this in a loop using a list of the variable names rather than making 20 assignments?